# Chat button in the question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Chat in [Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/) is not very popular so far. Most users do not know about the chat option. I think it is better to include the "Chat" button on the question itself to make people aware of it. This link will redirect people to chat.<link_to_the_question> link.

I discussed this feature-request in the "[Chat Feedback](http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/297#297)" Chat room but didn't receive any reply.

[image: Chat button]

Comment: +1 Very cool idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7) link on the top menu of every page:

[image]

There isn't a a link to create (or use) a specific chat room for a question. The traffic in our general room is probably low enough to discuss it there.

Comment: I don't find the chat link in the side bar, only in the bottom of the page but it takes to the general chat page, not to room to discuss the question.

Comment: @Rubén - cheers. The UI has been updated several times since I posted this answer.

Comment: I don't understand Meta yet, sorry. Should I add a comment to the question or should I post a new question / feature-request?

Comment: @Rubén - ah. I see (finally). I don't think there's a link to create (or use) a specific chat room for a question. The traffic in our general room is probably low enough to discuss it there.

Comment: I think that my concern has a stronger relationship with http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/685/discuss-a-particular-question-chat-faq?rq=1 but I would like to use the screen mockup in the question here.